# How to side-load data using web api and entity framework?

Tags: rest, api, api-design, entity-framework, web-api

I am working on a web api c# project using onion architecture and repository pattern and entity framework among other things. Doing some research I discovered a technique called **side-loading**

https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/side_loading

that basically helps client load additional information in a single rest api call.

Something like that is also mentioned in Json API 
http://jsonapi.org/examples/ as element "**included**"

Since this technique usually loads (but not necessarily) information store in different entities/repositories, I am not sure is this something that can or should be done in a single unit of work, or it has/should to be done through multiple database calls?